# CLI tools to publish a .sqlproj to database instance

Tags: sql-server, command-line-interface, sqlproj

I have a `.sqlproj` (Microsoft SQL Project) folder (Git repository) which I'd like to Publish to a live database instance using command line tools.

My colleague currently does this manually using Visual Studio:

1. Right-click on `Solution` then select `Rebuild solution`
2. Right-click on database project then select `Publish`
3. Load a profile from a .XML file (containing database connection string and a few other options)
4. Hit `Publish` to build this database on to the server specified in .XML file

How can I replicate this using command line tools? Preferably I would use Linux, but I'm open to using Windows options too as long as the process is fully automated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The CLI is [`sqlpackage.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage), available for Windows and Linux.

Comment: @DanGuzman does this work from a SQL Project? I'm looking at your link and all of its commands appear to work on an existing live database - which I don't have.

Comment: It uses the dacpac build artifact from the db project build. You need to first build the project, which can be done from the command-line (e.g. msbuild).

Comment: That's what I'm asking - what tools do I need to replicate the above process. If you're saying `msbuild` to create a DACPAC, then `sqlpackage` to publish this DACPAC to a live instance - great. Do you have any decent documentation for `msbuild`?

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say it's decent but you might peruse the [msbuild documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild). It seems it can also invoke the DacFx API directly instead of calling sqlpackage per [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild).